# Run a .swf game on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, games, flash, swf

I'm a Linux newbie and I know I might be doing something that I'd rather be doing on Windows. But I use Ubuntu on a daily basis, like how I used to do the same with Mint. I'm not much of a gamer, in fact, I'm not a gamer at all, but I do play visual novels from time to time.

I thought I'd try out one called Area-X this time. I remember playing a similar game on Windows (by the same people) and just like the other one this is a ".swf" game. Is there any way I can run this game like how Windows runs it like an .exe or in Firefox like a flash game?

I tried copying the directory address and pasting it on Firefox's URL bar but it shows me the "opening file" screen where you save/open files. It doesn't run the way it does by default on Windows, which is totally understandable since I'm using a different OS.

I'd like to just switch to my Windows, but it just broke out of the blue, literally. I haven't done anything to trigger it, it's like when you touch something and it shatters. But that's for another topic and I don't have any interest in restoring it.

If there's no way of running it on Linux I completely understand. Thanks! :)

Comment: Definitely a dupe, as far a that thread the 2nd answer (~/.mime.types ..) is best.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to define mime-type for flash

Somebody solved it => [Solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218732&page=2&p=13040642#post13040642)